# Configure nix-shell to use a shell other than Bash?

Tags: shell, configuration, development-environment, nixos

I'm on NixOS 15 and nix-shell v1.10.  I use Zsh as my main shell now, and would like to use it in conjuction with Oh-My-Zsh within the nix-shell as well when I'm working in development environments built by a Nix expression.

If it helps, here is one of the Nix environments I have set up for a Rails project:

```
with import <nixpkgs> {}; {
  cannyFreeRadicalEnv = stdenv.mkDerivation rec {
    name = "canny-free-radical-env";
    version = "0.1";
    src = ./.;
    buildInputs = [
        stdenv
        ruby_2_2_2
        bundler_HEAD
        zlib
        postgresql94
        sqlite
    ];
  };
}
```

**** Edit ****

Running the command this way does not indicate in the CLI prompt that I'm in the nix-shell.  Is there an easy way to detect this so that I can script it up quickly in my `zshrc`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

there is [PR #545](https://github.com/NixOS/nix/pull/545) opened recently which will address this

Answer (score 8):

Open a shell using:

```
nix-shell . --command "zsh"
```

Thanks to the guys on the #nixos IRC channel for getting me a quick answer.

Comment: I'm leaving this unaccepted in case someone has a better answer.  Maybe there is a way to do this that gets more to replacing the actual base shell nix-shell runs on?  I think using `--command` only executes Zsh from the original Bash shell on shell creation.

Comment: As it's been a few days, I'm assuming I won't get a better answer at this point.

Comment: This works well as long as you don't need to call the shell functions nix-shell generate (`configurePhase` etc)

Comment: Not enough information to help users of `zsh`.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try this Zsh plugin.

https://github.com/chisui/zsh-nix-shell

Answer (score 0):

[any-nix-shell](https://github.com/haslersn/any-nix-shell) worked for me. There is also a more manual approach presented here https://ianthehenry.com/posts/how-to-learn-nix/nix-zshell/

Note however that these solutions are not forwarding `alias` and phases like `unpackPhase`.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a trivial approach and it seems to be working.

```
$ alias nix-shell='nix-shell --run zsh'
```

It seems that providing `--run` multiple times results in the last one being used:

```
$ nix-shell -p cowsay --run 'cowsay a' --run 'cowsay b'
 ___
< b >
 ---
        \   ^__^
         \  (oo)\_______
            (__)\       )\/\
                ||----w |
                ||     ||
```

So this alias simply sets a default for `--run`.

Will this break anything? I can't imagine it will, but what do I know? It seems that aliases aren't exported to child shells.